# How to remove startup delay in audio live stream?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am using audio tag to play live stream in browser. here is the code i am using:

```
a1 = document.getElementById("a1");
var str = "/Live.mp3";
$("#a1").attr("src", str);
a1.load();
a1.play();
```

I am having delay of almost 10secs at startup. By using chrome's developer tools i found out chrome buffers 10secs of data before starting to play it. I want to play live stream so i can't afford startup delay. Is there any solution for this? I need to play audio as soon as button clicked.

Comment: well i have no technical detail to answer here m rather a tactical one , load a tiny start up stream first ,and play, then replace with actual when whole is loaded

Comment: I can't actually load audio before button click because for live stream i need to starts sound right from the time of click.